# Legal restrictions of using RC4 decoder

Tags: pdf, encryption, rc4-cipher

Does anybody know what exactly is protected by IP? Searching the RSA website for RC4 does not find any match.

From the PDF 1.7 documentation:

> Note: RC4 is a copyrighted, proprietary algorithm of RSA Security,
>   Inc. Adobe Systems has licensed this algorithm for use in its Acrobat
>   products. Independent software vendors may be required to license RC4
>   to develop software that encrypts or decrypts PDF documents. For
>   further information, visit the RSA Web site at <
>   http://www.rsasecurity.com > or send e-mail to <
>   products@rsasecurity.com >.

Answer (score 0):

RC4 was reverse engineered. Read the Wikipedia page. Implement. Copyright doesn't apply to cleanroom reverse engineering and the hard half has already been done for you.

Normally I'd tell you RC4 is not to be used but today you have an actual use case.